# Abrir arquivo com 2 cliques em um programa Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá. Estou criando um pequeno bloco de notas em Python e queria saber como eu abro um arquivo .txt usando ele a partir de 2 cliques no Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um arquivo .bat chama o python e associar os arquivos .txt a seu programa .bat.

arquivo.bat

```
python programa.py %1
```

Dessa forma é passado o nome do arquivo que você abriu é passado como argumento.

Para você pegar o nome do arquivo só precisa usar argv

import sys

```
sys.argv[0] # Sempre o caminho do programa
sys.argv[1] # O primeiro argumento, no seu caso o arquivo aberto.
```

Espero ter ajudado.

@gigafrota

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

No menu de contexto ir a Open With->Python e usar um script como este:

```
file = open("text1.txt", "r")

print(file.read())

input("Press Enter to quit: ")
```

Comment: Obrigado por tentar me ajudar, mas, o script precisa abrir junto com o arquivo ao dar dois cliques no windows explorer, tipo, arquivos .docx, ao dar 2 cliques nele o word abre mostrando o documento. No seu exemplo, o arquivo a ser aberto deve está pré-determinado

Comment: Com um ficheiro .bat é possível usar drag and drop para abrir um ficheiro dinamicamente.